# How to create a list of lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a start end, and a step, I would like to create a list like this (start= 0, end = 300, step = 100):

```
[[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300]]
```

The start, end, and step will vary, so I have to dynamically create the list.

Comment: Your list is inconsistent. You add 100 the first time, then 99 every other time..

Comment: Should the first list be `[1,100]`?

Comment: Sorry guys, the start is 1, and the step in this sample is 99. It will vary.

Comment: @user1842734: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13499080/edit) your question to show the true input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> start = 0
>>> end = 300
>>> step = 100
>>> [[1 + x, step + x] for x in range(start, end, step)]
[[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300]]
```

Comment: black_dragon this is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple while loop: -

```
start = 0
end = 300
step = 100

my_list = []

while start < end:   # Loop until you reach the end
    my_list.append([start + 1, start + step]) 
    start += step    # Increment start by step value to consider next group

print my_list
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300]]
```

The same thing can be achieved by `range` or `xrange` function, in a `list comprehension`.

Comment: Thank you all! You have been awesome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create two [`range`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them together:

```
def do_your_thing(start, end, step):
    return zip(range(start, end - step + 2, step),
               range(start + step - 1, end + 1, step))
```